# Where to find javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse for java. When I debug, 'source not found' came out, is it because of javadoc? Where can i find **javadoc** in my desktop?

Comment: I can find javadoc.exe in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin

Comment: I think that eclipse uses a javadoc library and does not need an external javadoc.exe binary.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your debugger stepped into a library class, and Eclipse cannot find the source for said library class.

You must tell Eclipse where the source files are located.

Comment: I think I do not have javadoc in my desktop, or I should download javadoc?

Comment: If you want to be able to trace through the source, you need the source files. Javadocs are similar, but not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to javadoc

When you debug and when you go to inside of a method to debug and if you call that method through a jar file you will get this "source not found". If you can use source codes instead of that jar you will not get that and it will direct you to required source line in that method.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse telling you that `source is not found` has nothing to do with javadoc, but with the actual java files.

Most probably you do not have your project configured has a java project with source folders configured. To configure your project source folders do the following:

1. Right click on your project's name in the navigator view
2. Select properties
3. Go to Java Build Path -> Source

Make sure all your source folders are there.
After making sure that all source folders are correctly configured, you should move on to your debug view, and while debugging:

1. Right click in the attached process
2. Select Edit Source Lookup
3. Make sure your project is in the list, otherwise add it.

It can also happen that Eclipse is trying to display you a source file which is not from your project but rather from some other jar you're using or from the actual Java Runtime.

If that's the case and you still want to debug that source too you have to download the source (the correct version you're using) and use the previous 3 steps in the debug view to add that source to your debug environment.